# Records, Zone doesn't displayed in Dashboard and Delete Zone issue CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have created a zone for `privateCloudDatabase`.

```
static var privateCloudDatabase: CKDatabase {
    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.<bundle>")
    return container.privateCloudDatabase
}

static func createZone() {
    let fetchZonesOperation = CKFetchRecordZonesOperation.fetchAllRecordZonesOperation()
    fetchZonesOperation.fetchRecordZonesCompletionBlock = {
        (recordZones: [CKRecordZone.ID : CKRecordZone]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }


        for recordID in recordZones.keys {
            if recordID.zoneName == zoneName {
                print("Zone Already Created: \(recordID)")
            } else if recordID.zoneName == "_defaultZone" {
                print("Deafult Zone")
            } else {
                let customZone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: zoneName)

                privateCloudDatabase.save(customZone) { zone, error in
                    if let error = error{
                        print("Zone creation error: \(String(describing: error))")
                    } else {
                        print("Zone created: \(String(describing: zone?.zoneID.zoneName))")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fetchZonesOperation.qualityOfService = .utility
    privateCloudDatabase.add(fetchZonesOperation)
}
```

It works successfully and I got a success message but created `Zone` doesn't display in CloudKit Dashboard. It only shows the `_default` zone as of now.

The other issue is related to delete all data from `Zone`. For that, I used below code

```
    let fetchZonesOperation = CKFetchRecordZonesOperation.fetchAllRecordZonesOperation()
    fetchZonesOperation.fetchRecordZonesCompletionBlock = {
        (recordZones: [CKRecordZone.ID : CKRecordZone]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let recordZones = recordZones else { return }

        let deletionOperation = CKModifyRecordZonesOperation(recordZonesToSave: nil, recordZoneIDsToDelete: recordZones.keys.map { $0 })

        deletionOperation.modifyRecordZonesCompletionBlock = { _, deletedZones, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                let error = error!
                print("Error deleting records.", error)
                return
            }

            print("Records successfully deleted in this zone.")
        }
    }
    fetchZonesOperation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
    privateCloudDatabase.add(fetchZonesOperation)
```

Here I neither get any success message not get any error message. The other method I tried to delete all data from the zone is

```
    let customZone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: zoneName)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: predicate)
    privateCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: customZone.zoneID) { (records, error) in
        if error == nil {
            for record in records! {
                removeRecord(record.recordID.recordName) { record, error in

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, I get the success message but when I am trying to fetch data from the zone, I get all entries and that suggests data aren't deleted using any of the above methods. Any suggestions for these queries?

Comment: check this for delete issues; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162395/why-is-ckmodifyrecordsoperation-to-batch-delete-records-in-cloudkit-not-deleting

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have run into inexplicable errors and the absence of data updates in CloudKit, it was usually because of something silly like:

1. A typo in the container identifier so it was interacting with the wrong database on CloudKit.
2. The account on my Apple device that I was using was different than the account I was signing into in the CloudKit Dashboard.

Have you checked the CloudKit logs to confirm that these actions are hitting your database?

Comment: Ok. I will check about cloudkit dashboard but what about delete records? As I can see even if I deleted records successfully, on fetch I gets data once again

Comment: And for the account, Is the admin access enough to check the cloudkit?